# How do I fix Python io.TextIOWrapper error message?

Tags: python

I know there are several post that have asked this question and I have tried some of the solutions but I still keep getting the error message. Both of the following solutions produce the same error message. What am I doing wrong?

Here is one solution I tried:

```
def main():
    #Open a file named numbers.txt
    numbers_file = open('numbers.txt','r')

    #read the numbers on the file
    file_contents = numbers_file.read()

    #Close the the numbers file
    numbers_file.close()

    #Print the data that was inside the file
    print(numbers_file)

#Call the main function
main()
```

Here is another solution I tried:

```
with open(r"numbers.txt",'r') as numbers_file:
    #read the numbers on the file
    file_contents = numbers_file.read()

    #Close the the numbers file
    numbers_file.close()

    #Print the data that was inside the file
    print(numbers_file)
```

The error message I get when I run either of the programs is:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='numbers.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Comment: Could you add more details? Now it is not clear what is your problem and how to reproduce it.

Comment: I am trying to open a notepad file that I saved as numbers.txt. It has a few groups of numbers in it.

Comment: That's not an error message, you're just printing the wrong thing. You wanted to print `file_contents`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the help. I realized what I was doing wrong. Here is what I got:

```
def main():
    #Open a file named numbers.txt
    numbers_file = open('numbers.txt','r')

    #read the numbers on the file
    file_contents = numbers_file.read()

    #Close the the numbers file
    numbers_file.close()

    #Print the data that was inside the file
    print(file_contents)

#Call the main function
main()
```